# Как работает getElementById

Tags: javascript, dom

Ребята вопрос в следующем. Есть код

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='task_1'>
    <iframe id="iframe" src="index1.html" frameborder="1"></iframe>
    <button id="reload" value="reload">Reload page</button>
    <button id="open_new" value="open_new">Open new page</button>
    <button id="update_iframe" value="update_iframe">Update iframe</button>
    <button id="back" value="back">Come back</button>
    <button id="other" value="other">Other</button>
</div>
<script>
   var contex = document.getElementById('task_1');
   context.getElementById("reload");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Сразу оговорюсь что я понимаю что можно найти сразу, на прямую элемент с id = "reload", но реализация должна проходить именно так.
Так вот вопрос: почему когда вызываем на прямую (document.getElementById('reload')) все работает, а если context.getElementById("reload") то пишет TypeError: context.getElementById is not a function.
Посмотрел в **proto** там действительно нет getElementById(), пожалуйста объясните почему так или дайте ссылку на статью, а также если знаете как решить данный вопрос - скажите))) Всем спасибо!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 2):

[`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) - это метод у `document` корневого. Его нету у дочерних элементов.

Можно искать по классу, используя `getElementsByClassName` на полученном `div`'е.

Что-то типо такого:

```js
function searchElements(selector, context){
    if(context === null || context === undefined)
        context = document;

    var itemIndex = selector.indexOf("#");
    if(itemIndex != -1){
        var itemId = selector.substring(itemIndex + 1);
        return context.getElementById(itemId);
    }

    var classIndex = selector.indexOf(".");
    if(classIndex != -1){
        var className = selector.substring(classIndex + 1);
        return context.getElementsByClassName(className);
    }
    
    return context.getElementsByTagName(selector);
}
console.log(searchElements("#update_iframe"));
console.log(searchElements(".reload"));
console.log(searchElements("button"));
```

```html
<div id="task_1">
    <button id="reload" class="reload" value="reload">Reload page</button>
    <button id="open_new" value="open_new">Open new page</button>
    <button id="update_iframe" value="update_iframe">Update iframe</button>
    <button id="back" value="back">Come back</button>
    <button id="other" value="other">Other</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Это я как бы понимаю, но есть задача и как ее решить не пойму)
может я конечно не верно толкую условия задачи

Comment: Вот сама задача
Написати функцію searchElements(selector, context), яка шукає всі елементи які
відповідають селектору selector всередині елементу context (якщо не вказаний
то у всьому документі).
selector може мати наступні види:
● для пошуку всіх тегів з відповідним іменем: div
● для пошуку по класу: .some-class
● для пошуку по id: #element
Використовувати наступні функції : getElementsByClassName(),
getElementsByTagName(), document.getElementById()

Comment: @Slava я украинского не знаю =/

Comment: Написать функцию searchElements(selector, context), которая ищет все элементы которые соответствуют селектру selector внутри элемента context (если не указано то во всем документе).
selector может иметь следущие виды:
● для поиска всех теговс соответствующим именем: div
● для поиска по классу: .some-class
● для поиска по id: #element
Используйте следующие функции : getElementsByClassName(),
getElementsByTagName(), document.getElementById()

Comment: @Slava обновил ответ. Дальше сами.

Comment: @Suvitruf, а что дальше? Уже ответили :)

Comment: @Other ну там не в унифицированном виде возвращаемое значение у функции. Хорошо бы причесать ^_^

Comment: @Suvitruf, угу, а ещё ошибки поправить, годно учите, товарищ!

Comment: @Other я показываю лишь направление. Желательно, чтоб и авторы вопросов серым веществом поработали (:

Comment: @Suvitruf, направление - это почти готовый код?

Comment: @Other почти (;

Comment: @Suvitruf, дьявол в деталях :) Нужно ли новичку **так** делать демо?

Comment: @Other кто знает :C

Comment: @Slava - скажите задавателю задания, что знаете про функцию `querySelector`, и получите пятерку - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp

Comment: Всем спасибо! Искать по классу это хорошо, но есть задание и надо ему следовать. Задания я сделал, теперь буду ждать результат)))